# How to build cmake-project with atom text editor?

Tags: build, cmake, atom-editor

I've installed packages build and build-make, and it's not obvious what to do next. 
Build-tools package is bugged and impossible to install now.

I have cmake project, sucsessfully build in different IDE: QTCreator, VisualStudio, via bash. So i want to make it with atom, and there is no instruction how to use it's build-make package. Documentation to this package is empty.

in bash i call: `cmake ../src` from my build dir. 
So in `.atom-build.json` i put this command and point directory as working - and nothing happens, on f9 i've god `"Cannot read peoperty "exec" or undefined"`

Comment: Please explain more verbose what you want to do. Most probably atom is unrelated to your question.

Comment: Atom is related. I have cmake project, sucsessfully build in different IDE: QTCreator, VisualStudio, via bash. So i want to make it with atom, and there is no instruction how to use it's build-make package. Documentation to this package is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `CMake` and `make` are two different things.

What you are looking for is a CMake plugin for Atom, of which there are currently none.  (Some for syntax highlighting but none for running graphically...)

If you have CMake working in other IDEs then you shouldn't have a problem running CMake from the command line:

```
cd /path/to/project
cmake .
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, there is a cmake package for Atom.

Here you go:
https://atom.io/packages/build-cmake

Comment: It's broken for me (runs only once)